# NPM Error When Trying To Install Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I can't install Angular CLI in my local desktop, as it is giving some JAVA path error.

I have tried to install Angular CLI with and without java. However, I still can't install Angular CLI.

**Error Message:**

> C:\Users\Anindya>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
>
> npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
>
> npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.0.1 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
>
> npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.0.1 postinstall script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anindya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-04T06_19_01_033Z-debug.log

[image]

Comment: Did you add node to your `PATH` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your `PATH`variable: JAVA & Node.

Try to run `npm cache clean --force` before install @angular/cli

Comment: thanks, I have added PATH variable: JAVA & Node. I also executed the command npm cache clean --force before install @angular/cli. However, system threw same error message Error Logs --- 6993 verbose stack Error: @angular/cli@8.0.1 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
6993 verbose stack spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin ENOENT
6993 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
6993 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)

Comment: C:\Users\Anindya>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windo
ws;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\
bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\I
ntel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
1.8.0_211\bin;C:\Users\Anindya\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: same problem with other angular versions ?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCJxl.png)Hi All,

Thanks for all your support. The issue was with my Windows 7 OS.
I updated my OS to Windows 8 and  successfully installed angular js